# Update an existing associate in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The `update` function which I have defined is working but I am wondering whether I can clean this code. The update function and association with the `$token` is working, but I was wondering whether it be possible to associate the `$connector` with the `$token` within the `->update` (so I don't have to save AND update my instance!).

```
public function update(Requests\StoreConnectorRequest $request, connector $connector)
    {
        $token = Token::findOrFail($request->input('tokenId'));

        $connector->update([
            'name'      => $request->input('name'),
            'type'      => $request->input('type'),
            'schedule'  => $request->input('schedule')
        ]);

        $connector->token()->associate($token);    
        $connector->save();  

        return redirect()->route('connector.index');
    }
```

Comment: I think I don't get your relationships. Your token hasMany connections or your connection hasMany tokens?

Comment: connector->belongsTo(token)

Comment: Ok try with my answer. And see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You could change method `update` to `fill`. So it won't get saved twice.
But remember you have to add the required fields to the `fillable` property in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$token = Token::findOrFail($request->input('tokenId'));
$token->connectors()->update([
     'id'   => $connector->id, //important 
     'name' => $request->input('name'),
     ...
]);
```

I hope this works.